# Customizable Forecasts vs Forecasts

Tags: forecast

I have been digging deep into the annals of Forecasting features lately, and have found myself swimming in a sea of confusing documentation. So far I have come across three flavours of Forecasting:

1. Classic (pre customizable forecasting feature)
2. Customizable Forecasting (not available to customers after Winter '12)
3. Forecasts (released in Winter '12)

Presumably Forecasts is the latest version, and should be used for new orgs, however if you [contrast the features](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=faq_forecasts3_whats_difference_between_versions.htm&language=en_US) of Customizable Forecasts (CF) vs Forecasts, you can see that CF has more features than Forecasts.

[image]

How is this possible? Is my analysis wrong, or is the documentation out-of-date?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. *Forecasts* was released with Winter '12, but I would consider it to be still in beta. It is not possible to combine with certain other high-impact features such as *Territory Management* and *multi-currency* (as your table clearly states).

If you are not currently using e.g. *Territory Management* or *multi-currency*, or any of the other features incompatible with *Forecasts*, I'd suggest going with *Forecasts* anyway. They will surely be adding on features to it with later releases, to get it up to par with Customizable Forecasting.

Comment: Hi @jliljegren-c, it would be appreciated if you could confirm that the new version of forecasts is not compatible with multi-currency? I.e. If you currently have customisable forecasting and wish to use multi-currency in future then you cannot move to the new forecasts... Yet?

Comment: Mutli currency is now supported with Collaborative Forecasts

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, only Collaborative Forecasts work with Multi-Currency... not Customizable Forecasts.
http://login.salesforce.com/help/doc/en/forecasts3_multiple_currencies.htm